# Possibilities for sending push-notifications from a PHP webserver to an android smartwatch (without using Firebase/GCM etc.)

Tags: php, android, laravel, wear-os, android-push-notification

I am looking for Options to send push-notifications from laravel-php-web applications to an Android smartwatch. But I do not want to use any cloud service like Google Cloud Messaging or Google Firebase etc, because I don't want to share the sent sensible data with Google or another company.

Do you maybe have any suggestions about how to implement something like this?

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please can you provide what you have tried? [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid using Google Firebase, you could make use of another service like [Pusher](https://pusher.com/tutorials/web-notifications-laravel-pusher-channels) or PubNub.
You could also make your own Pub/Sub server with [Socket.io](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-laravel-with-socket-io-e7c7565cc19d/) or the new [Laravel-WebSockets](https://murze.be/introducing-laravel-websockets-an-easy-to-use-websocket-server-implemented-in-php) library, a library that use the same API as Pusher (for easy integration). This last option is the one I'd recommend. You can check [this channel for an in-deep tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pIGy7-7gGXI).

In order to make Laravel-WebSockets to work with Android, just use the Pusher library for Android and set your host variables and keys in the config.